# Unable to assign random texts to event click in javascript

Tags: javascript

Try to run below but it says await can only be used on async function. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. I am trying to just create some random texts and bring it back to loop and assign to each click.. Please advise. thank you. so lost.

```js
const alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'x', 'w', 'y', 'z']

const getRandomInt = (min, max) => {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min); // 
}

const createRandomShit = async() => {
  const overallTimes = getRandomInt(50, 500)
  let masterReturn = '';
  [...Array(overallTimes)].map((_, i) => {
    let randAlaph = getRandomInt(1, 24)
    let whichLetterToPick = alphabet[randAlaph]
    masterReturn += whichLetterToPick
  })
  console.log(masterReturn)
}

c.forEach(ch => {
  ch.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const d = new Date()
    contentShowOutput.textContent = ''
    let j = await createRandomShit()
    contentShowOutput.textContent = 'testing... ' + j
  })
})
```

UPDATE:

Below seems to work.. but am i doing it correctly?

```
const alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'x', 'w', 'y', 'z']

const getRandomInt = (min, max) => {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min); // 
}

const createRandomShit = async() => {
    const overallTimes = getRandomInt(50, 500)
    let masterReturn = '';
    [...Array(overallTimes)].map((_, i) => {
        let randAlaph = getRandomInt(1, 24)
        let whichLetterToPick = alphabet[randAlaph]
        masterReturn += whichLetterToPick
    })
    return masterReturn
    console.log(masterReturn)
}

c.forEach(ch => {
    ch.addEventListener('click', async() => {
        const d = new Date()
        contentShowOutput.textContent = ''
        let j = await createRandomShit()
        console.log("j", j)
        contentShowOutput.textContent = 'testing... ' + j
    })
})
```

Comment: You don't need async here.

Comment: Also,  await can only be used on an async function, but you are trying to use it within non-asnyc function.

Comment: Just remove `await` ???